# Unit Testing validates presence of odd behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, validation, testing

I'm trying out the whole TDD and I'm running into a problems with validate presence. I have a model called `Event` and I want to ensure that when an `Event` is created that a `title` a `price` and a `summary` exists.

**Unit Test Code**

```
class EventTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "should not save without a Title" do
    event = Event.new
    event.title = nil
    assert !event.save, "Save the Event without title"
  end

  test "should not save without a Price" do
    event = Event.new
    event.price = nil
    assert !event.save, "Saved the Event without a Price"
  end

  test "should not save without a Summary" do
    event = Event.new
    event.summary = nil
    assert !event.save, "Saved the Event without a Summary"
  end

end
```

I run the test I get **3 FAILS. Which is Good.**
Now I want to to just get the `title` test to pass first with the following code in the `Event` model.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :title, :presence => true

end
```

When I re-run the test I get **3 PASSES** where I would think I should have gotten **1 PASS and 2 FAILS**. Why am I getting 3 PASSES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two test helper methods that can make this sort of thing easier to diagnose:

```
def assert_created(model)
  assert model, "Model was not defined"
  assert_equal [ ], model.errors.full_messages
  assert model.valid?, "Model failed to validate"
  assert !model.new_record?, "Model is still a new record"
end

def assert_errors_on(model, *attrs)
  found_attrs = [ ]

  model.errors.each do |attr, error|
    found_attrs << attr
  end

  assert_equal attrs.flatten.collect(&:to_s).sort, found_attrs.uniq.collect(&:to_s).sort
end
```

You'd use them in cases like this:

```
test "should save with a Title, Price or Summary" do
  event = Event.create(
    :title => 'Sample Title',
    :price => 100,
    :summary => 'Sample summary...'
  )

  assert_created event
end

test "should not save without a Title, Price or Summary" do
  event = Event.create

  assert_errors_on event, :title, :price, :summary
end
```

This should show if you're missing a validation that you expected and will also give you feedback on specific validations that have failed when not expected.

Answer (score 1):

When you created the model with `Event.new`, all attributes initially have a value of `nil`.  This means that all 3 attributes you are checking are already nil (so `event.title = nil` and `event.price = nil` don't actually do anything).  Since `title` has been marked for validation to ensure its presence, unless you set `title` to something other than nil, you will not be able to save the model.

Perhaps try adding this to your test class:

```
setup do
  @event_attributes = {:title => "A title", :price => 3.99, :summary => "A summary"}
end
```

Then instead of:

```
event = Event.new
event.title = nil
```

Use:

```
event = Event.new(@event_attributes.merge(:title => nil))
```

Do the same for all your tests (substituting `:title` with whatever attribute you are validating presence for)

Also, there's no reason to call `save` to test for a valid state.  You can just call `event.valid?` to avoid trips to the database where not needed.

Comment: So how else can I write this test to make sure that the specific attributes 'title', 'price', 'summary' are present?