# Is there a Lint for ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, activerecord

Rubyists, particularly Railsers, know all about [ActiveModel::Lint](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Lint/Tests.html), which is a handy way to ensure that you haven't cocked up when writing your ActiveModel subclass, and saves hours of head-scratching. I use it all the time for table-less models in Rails projects.

But I spend a lot of time hunting down errors with my usage of ActiveRecord - particularly with double-sided associations. For example

```
# app/models/blog.rb
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts # so far so good...
end

# app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :blog # incorrect - should be belongs_to
end
```

That example is somewhat contrived, as nobody's *that* silly. But what if `Blog` actually has a `post_id` column? Exceptions would not be raised where expected.

I'd like to be able to write a test for `Blog` like this

```
# test/unit/blog_test.rb
require 'test/test_helper'
class BlogTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include ActiveRecord::Lint
end
```

...and the test output should say something like `Blog :has_many :posts, but Post does not :belong_to :blog!`. It would need to reflect on the associations, dealing with table-names, foreign-keys, etc, and considering :through models on the way. I know that proper unit tests will detect these issues anyway, but generally as side-effects of other tests.

Does anyone know of a project which does this? (I'm only interested in ActiveRecord >= 3.1). All I could find was [active_record_lint](https://github.com/cwninja/active_record_lint), which doesn't really do this at all.

Additionally, it would be great if all the existing fixtures could be tested automatically, to make sure that those pesky associations are set up. I usually just do

```
test "fixtures" do
  Post.all.each { |p| assert p.valid? "Fixture is broken! #{p.inspect}" }
end
```

but there's surely a more elegant way.

Comment: If you use fixtures instead of factories, it's a good plan to test them like you do. All too easy to make broken fixtures and then spend hours trying to track down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A tool like this would be useful, but you should be testing these things explicitly anyway. This will uncover problems like this immediately. For instance, a typical unit test:

```
def test_defaults
  blog = Blog.create(
    :title => 'Example Blog'
  )

  assert blog.valid?
  assert_equal [ ], blog.errors.full_messages
  assert !blog.new_record?

  assert_equal 0, blog.posts.count
end
```

For your post:

```
def test_defaults
  blog = Blog.create(
    :title => 'Example Blog'
  )

  post = Post.create(
    :blog => blog,
    :content => 'Blogging blog bloggers blogged blogs'
  )

  assert post.valid?
  assert_equal [ ], post.errors.full_messages
  assert !post.new_record?

  assert_equal blog.id, post.blog_id
  assert_equal 1, blog.posts.count
end
```

Those are the long form versions of some [helper methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993068/unit-testing-validates-presence-of-odd-behaviour/8994323#8994323) that I usually use.

If you don't exercise the relationships, you're not testing them and you've got a problem with your test coverage. If you exercise a bad relationship it will show up as an error.

Comment: I completely agree, and it's what I normally do, too, defining `assert_valid` in the test_helper.rb.I have a pretty convoluted structure in an app at the moment, where a Category `:has_many (several models)`, and `has_many :categorizables` and `:has_many :other_models, :through => :categorizables (extra options)`. It's a nightmare to test, even using helpers, and it starts to feel repetitive and WET (What, Every Time?). These tests *should* be pretty standardizable, I was wondering whether anyone had taken the time to produce an off-the shelf gem which checks the associations. If not, I might.

Comment: Remember that you test a particular function once in each of its various forms, not every time you might happen to use it. That is, check the empty state, add something, check the state, remove something, check again. There's no need to assert the same thing over and over and over. If one test fails and a bunch error out, you fix the failing test first on the premise it may fix the errors.